# Optimization of F# string manipulation

Tags: string, f#

I am just learning F# and have been converting a library of C# extension methods to F#.  I am currently working on implementing a function called ConvertFirstLetterToUppercase based on the **C# implementation below**:

```
public static string ConvertFirstLetterToUppercase(this string value) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
    if (value.Length == 1) return value.ToUpper();
    return value.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + value.Substring(1);
}
```

**The F# implementation**

```
[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute>]
module public StringHelper
    open System
    open System.Collections.Generic
    open System.Linq

    let ConvertHelper (x : char[]) =  
        match x with
            | [| |] | null -> ""
            | [| head; |] -> Char.ToUpper(head).ToString()
            | [| head; _ |] -> Char.ToUpper(head).ToString() + string(x.Skip(1).ToArray())

    [<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute>]
    let ConvertFirstLetterToUppercase (_this : string) =
        match _this with
        | "" | null -> _this
        | _ -> ConvertHelper (_this.ToCharArray())
```

Can someone show me a more concise implementation utilizing more natural F# syntax?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, I learned some new operators and how to use pattern matching. :-)  I guess next step?  Performance testing? lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute>]
module public StringHelper = 
[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute>]
let ConvertFirstLetterToUppercase (t : string) =
    match t.ToCharArray() with
    | null -> t
    | [||] -> t
    | x -> x.[0] <- Char.ToUpper(x.[0]); System.String(x)
```

Comment: I like this one, just a note, you can combine the null or empty array checks with the following to reduce line count:

| null | [||] -> this

Answer (score 17):

```
open System

type System.String with
    member this.ConvertFirstLetterToUpperCase() =
        match this with
        | null -> null
        | "" -> ""
        | s -> s.[0..0].ToUpper() + s.[1..]
```

Usage:

```
> "juliet".ConvertFirstLetterToUpperCase();;
val it : string = "Juliet"
```

Comment: Now if you want something a little more efficient than substrings, try `let chars = s.ToCharArray(); chars.[0] <- Char.ToUpper(chars.[0]); new String(chars)`

Comment: +1, love the use of [n..n].  Haven't seen that applied in a good case bofer.

Comment: Is the array version really faster? The substring version makes a copy of almost the whole string (s.[1..]) and then another string is created when that string is added to the first char. The array version copies the string to an array, then the array is copied to a string. Seems like 2 copy operations either way - or is array conversion faster than string copying?

Comment: You could add an extra case after null/empty string as: | s when s.Length = 1 -> s.ToUpper ()

Comment: how would you define this in the global namespace, such that you don't have to open the module it is defined in to consume it?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute>]
module StringExtensions = 
    let ConvertFirstLetterToUpperCase (data:string) =
        match Seq.tryFind (fun _ -> true) data with
        | None -> data
        | Some(c) -> System.Char.ToUpper(c).ToString() + data.Substring(1)
```

The `tryFind` function will return the first element for which the lambda returns `true`.  Since it always returns true it will simply return the first element or `None`.  Once you've established there is at least one element you know `data` is not `null` and hence can call Substring

Comment: I like the solution!  I was kind of hoping that cons would work with arrays so I could do pattern matching on the expression that actually created the result, but alas, that is not part of the implementation. :-/

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using .NET library functions from a .NET language. Maybe a direct translation of your C# extension method is most appropriate, particularly for such a simple function. Although I'd be tempted to use the slicing syntax like Juliet does, just because it's cool.

```
open System
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
module public StringHelper =

    [<Extension>]
    let ConvertFirstLetterToUpperCase(this:string) =
        if String.IsNullOrEmpty this then this
        elif this.Length = 1 then this.ToUpper()
        else this.[0..0].ToUpper() + this.[1..]
```

Comment: I really prefer the use of the intrinsic language features over the Framework API's just because of the less verbose language style.

Comment: This seems like a clean solution to me, even if it doesn't seem very idiomatic.